# Java Calendar.set not giving correct result

Tags: java, date, calendar

I can't see where I'm going wrong with the code below, its probably something obvious but I'm too  blind to see it at this stage. I'm passing a date of "01/01/2009" to an instance of calendar. I then try and set the month to 2 for March and the output I see is

formatted: 01/01/2009

cal month: 2

```
cal.set( Calendar.MONTH, mth ); //mth = int 2

log.debug("formatted: " + formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
log.debug("cal month: "+Integer.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)).toString());
```

When I set the Calendar.DAY to the max value the date comes out as 
31/01/2009

Why does my setting of the Month not take?

Comment: Give us actual working code that reproduces the error - excerpts like the above usually miss the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll look into exactly what's going on, but the general rule of thumb is: **don't use java.util.{Date,Calendar}**. Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead... it's *so* much cleaner...

EDIT: I can't reproduce your issue at the moment. I'd still recommend using Joda, but if you could post a short but *complete* program to demonstrate the problem, we may be able to work out what's going wrong.

EDIT: Based on another comment, I wonder whether your formatter is wrong... are you really using "dd/mm/yyyy" rather than "dd/MM/yyyy"? "mm" means minutes, not months.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 8):

We ran into this and the result was that the value you set doesn't get used until you actually try to 'get' the value from Calendar.  We were puzzled because using the debugger the value never seemed to get set, but when you actually 'get' it, it works.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Getting and Setting Calendar Field Values

The calendar field values can be set by calling the set methods. Any field values set in a Calendar will not be interpreted until it needs to calculate its time value (milliseconds from the Epoch) or values of the calendar fields. Calling the get, getTimeInMillis, getTime, add and roll involves such calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you wanted to use Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH